# How to let geom_text inherit theme specifications? (ggplot2)

Tags: r, ggplot2, themes, ggrepel

Is there an elegant way in `ggplot2` to make `geom_text`/`geom_label` inherit `theme` specifications like a `base_family`?

Or asked the other way round: Can I specify a `theme` that also applies to `geom_text`/`geom_label`?

---

**Example:**

I want `text/labels` to look exactly like the `axis.text` as specified in the `theme`...

Obviously I could add the specifications manually as optional arguments to `geom_text`, but I want it to inherit the specifications "automatically"...

```
library("ggplot2")

ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = mpg,
                   y = hp,
                   label = row.names(mtcars))) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_text() +
  theme_minimal(base_family = "Courier")
```

[image: <code>theme</code> specifications not inherited]

Addition: A solution that works with `ggrepel::geom_text_repel/geom_label_repel` as well would be perfect...

Comment: `theme` only affects the non-data aspects of the plot. You may have a look at [`update_geom_defaults`](http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/update_defaults.html) ([examples on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5br%5d%20update_geom_defaults))

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can

### Setting Overall font

Firstly, depending on the system you will need to check which fonts are available. As I am running on Windows I am using the following:

```
install.packages("extrafont")
library(extrafont)
windowsFonts() # check which fonts are available
```

The `theme_set` function lets you specify the overall themes for ggplot. So therefore `theme_set(theme_minimal(base_family = "Times New Roman"))` lets you define the fonts for the plot.

### Make Labels Inherit Font

To make the labels inherit this text, there are two things we need to use:

1. `update_geom_defaults` lets you update the geometry object styling for future plots in ggplot: http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/update_defaults.html
2. `theme_get()$text$family` extracts the font of the current global ggplot theme.

By combining these two, the label styles can be updated as follows:

```
# Change the settings
update_geom_defaults("text", list(colour = "grey20", family = theme_get()$text$family))
update_geom_defaults("text_repel", list(colour = "grey20", family = theme_get()$text$family))
```

### Results

```
theme_set(theme_minimal(base_family = "Times New Roman"))

# Change the settings
update_geom_defaults("text", list(colour = "grey20", family = theme_get()$text$family))

# Basic Plot
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = mpg,
                   y = hp,
                   label = row.names(mtcars))) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_text()
```

[image]

```
# works with ggrepel
update_geom_defaults("text_repel", list(colour = "grey20", family = theme_get()$text$family))

library(ggrepel)

ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = mpg,
                   y = hp,
                   label = row.names(mtcars))) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_text_repel()
```

[image]

Comment: great answer, well illustrated